# Release to refresh on Android aka Overscroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Sencha Touch has release to refresh. In other words, you drag a list down an a nice little animation shows up.  Are there any native Android libraries for release to refesh a ListActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going into the land of overscroll. This might help you: https://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-overscroll-revisited/

Comment: Thanks !! Exactly the help I needed!